# Ubuntu Minimal of less than 100 MB

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want a minimal Ubuntu of less than 100 MB after installation!! Ubuntu with only terminal no GUI!!! Actually i want to install a terminal based Ubuntu with no GUI as my virtual machine Can anybody help???

Comment: cross posting http://askubuntu.com/questions/687961/ubuntu-minimal-of-less-than-100-mb

Answer (score 1):

You are looking, in capability, for [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), but it is not < 100MB; it is roughly 600MB.

A [Debian Netinst](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) (minimal) is ~200MB for amd64.

You might try looking at some of the more uncommon systems like Slackware, Arch or Gentoo for this kind of customization.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [debian](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/), you can download the ubuntu mini.iso.

The mini.iso is a netinstall image and is great for doing what you want to do. When you get to the part of the installation that lists the different desktops, just basically unselect everything or almost everything.

You may want some minimal stuff like a server of maybe not, the choice is up to you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD